# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. while trying to run application

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

When I tring to runs application gives below error. gradle build successfully

```
 2021-12-07T12:16:33.071+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.071+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.071+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.071+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.072+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.072+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.072+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.072+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.073+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.074+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.074+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.075+0530 [WARN] [org.gradle.internal.featurelifecycle.LoggingDeprecatedFeatureHandler] 
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.075+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
    2021-12-07T12:16:33.076+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 2m 18s
```

getting above error every time when I trying to run project

**Using build.gradle**

```
>   compileSdkVersion 31   //buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
>     defaultConfig {
>         minSdkVersion 23
>         targetSdkVersion 31
>         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>         multiDexEnabled true
>         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
>         renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
>         aaptOptions {
>             additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
>         }
>         resConfigs "en", "hi"
>     }
```

**Using below gradle.properties**

```
>  distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
>     distributionPath=wrapper/dists
>     zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
>     zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
>     distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
>     ./gradlew=lint -Xlint\:deprecation
```

**steps that I followed**

1. clean build
2. Invalidate and restart
3. delete .gradle and restart
4. update jdk/jre
5. reinstall android studio

when I do --warning-mode all,
it will shows

```
> The following annotation processors are not incremental:
> jetified-butterknife-compiler-10.0.0.jar
> (com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0). Make sure all
> annotation processors are incremental to improve your build speed. An
> exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_312). Please file a bug
> against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page
> (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database
> (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the
> following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
> java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute
> name MODULE (class
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)  at
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)    at
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
>   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
>   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitVarDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1164)
>   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
>   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
>   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
>   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
>   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
>   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
>   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152)   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)    at
> com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
>   at
> com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
>   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)     at
> com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
>   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.IncrementalCompileTask.call(IncrementalCompileTask.java:74)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:94)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:55)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:40)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:97)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:46)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:36)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompiler.execute(CleaningJavaCompiler.java:53)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory.lambda$createRebuildAllCompiler$0(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:98)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:61)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:45)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:343)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performIncrementalCompilation(JavaCompile.java:237)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:209)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)    at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:555)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:540)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:523)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:271)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:260)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:33)
>   at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)    at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:42)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
>   at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)    at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
>   at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)  at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:179)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 
> > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: have you followed this advice? `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.`. this may come from some dependency lib, not neccessary your code

Comment: yes it will gives An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_312). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)